# Sort a DropdownLIst populated by ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, .net

I am populating a DropdownLIst from an ObjectDataSource. The ObjectDataSource gets it values from a service. The service delivers the results unsorted. Is there  way I can sort the by DataTextField before the data is bound to the DropdownList? I feel like there should be a way to do this within the client-side here, but I don't know how. Suggestions please?
(.net 4.5)

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AffiliationDropDownList" runat="server"
            ClientIDMode="Static" Width="200px" 
            DataSourceID="AffiliationObjectDataSource" 
            DataTextField="AffiliateName" 
            DataValueField="AffiliateID" 
            AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
            AutoPostBack="false" >
            <asp:ListItem Text="All Affiliations" Value="" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="AffiliationObjectDataSource" 
            SelectMethod="RetrieveActiveAffiliations" 
            TypeName="OnlineVolunteerApplication.Data.VolunteerService.VolunteerServiceClient" >
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: I believe you need to be looking at the DataView object, it's been awhile though.

Comment: Do you need to use the ObjectDataSource as a data source or can you query the service and get a collection instead? This would allow you to use LINQ for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this in your select method `RetrieveActiveAffiliations`. You can see the details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.sortparametername.aspx)

```
DataView dv = new DataView(yourtable);
dv.Sort = "id asc"; //your sort expression
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this:-

```
DataView defaultView = dataSource.Tables[0].DefaultView;
DataTable dt = getData();
dt.DefaultView.Sort= "UserName DESC";
```